# Effect of origin poles on stability?

Tags: poles-zeros, stability, control-systems

What will be stability if we have only one single pole at origin in s domain??
and what will be the case for multiple poles at origin in s domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A system with simple distinct poles on the imaginary axis (and note that the origin is on the imaginary axis) and no poles in the right half-plane is called [marginally stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_stability). If you have poles with multiplicity greater than $1$ on the imaginary axis, or if there are poles in the right half-plane, then the system is unstable.

For discrete-time systems, the same is true if you replace "imaginary axis" by "unit circle".

Transients in marginally stable systems do not decay, but neither do they grow without bounds. In practice, we usually want to avoid marginally stable systems. An ideal integrator is an example of a marginally stable system.

Comment: What do you mean in first line??any pole on imaginary axis is also on origin?(it is definitely origin with regard to x axis,but might or might not be origin with regard to y axis)

Comment: I would like to expand a little with regards to stability. There are many definitions in control theory for stability, such as BIBO, asymptotic, exponential and Lyapunov. For simple poles on the imaginary axis (and no right half plane poles) only satisfies Lyapunov stability and not any of the other mentioned stability criteria. And all mentioned criteria fail when you have a non-simple pole on the imaginary axis. It can be noted that you can have multiple poles on the imaginary axis, as long as they are all simple, and still be Lyapunov stable.

Comment: @abtj: It's just as I said, the origin $s=0$ is on the imaginary axis, so a pole at $s=0$ is on the imaginary axis. And, obviously, not all poles on the imaginary axis are necessarily at the origin.

Comment: @abtj imaginary axis just means a pole with zero real part; its imaginary part can be anything. This is also true for the origin (the origin has both zero real and zero imaginary part).

Comment: @MattL. same ruling for Z domain??if we have single pole on unit circle,it is marginally stable ??and if multiple poles on unit circle,will it be unstable??

Comment: @abtj: That's right!

Comment: @abtj A simple digital resonator can have two poles on the z-plane's unit circle and not be unstable. Such a resonator would instead be marginally stable.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, it is not about the *number* of poles on the unit circle, but about the *multiplicity* of the poles. Separate simple poles on the unit circle, no matter how many, result in a marginally stable system, poles on the circle with multiplicity greater than $1$ cause the system to be unstable.